# Asp.net Core Log all SQL queries in middleware

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to log every SQL request in a request to the database with a middleware. so far I have only managed to create an empty middleware that is hit by every request but I have no idea how to get the SQL queries from that request.

I have read a few articles ([1](https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-middleware-to-log-requests-and-responses-in-asp-net-core/)) about how to log requests and responses with middleware but they are getting the whole request (the whole HTML page) and I only want the SQL queries. so how can I get those queries?

```
    public class LoggingEveryRequestToLogDataBase
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public LoggingEveryRequestToLogDataBase(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ILogDbContext dbContext)
    {
        var request = new 
        {
            ipAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(),
            path = context.Request.Host + context.Request.Path + context.Request.QueryString,
        };

        await _next(context);
    }

}

public static class LoggingEveryRequestToLogDataBaseMiddleware
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder LoggingEveryRequestToLogDataBase(
        this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<LoggingEveryRequestToLogDataBase>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You won't get any SQL query by logging requests and responses. The response typically contains information created by the server. During that period the server may have submitted queries to the database but those are obviously not visible in the response, only the result is, and even then represented by html or json. To log SQL queries you need something else than asp.net middleware. What database are you using and how do you access it? Are you for example using entity framework?

Comment: As @PeterBons suggested above, middleware sits in your request processing pipeline. If you consider lifecycle of a web request, it is - user web page TO web server TO .net processing pipeline TO application logic TO database RETURN data TO processing logic TO response construction TO processing pipeline TO web server TO user's browser. What is the problem you are trying to solve? Nature of problem determines whether you should capture query in application or in database profiler.

Comment: it is an SQL server and I'm using ef, I think it is possible to get pure SQL code, like `select * from user`, I want to log those.

Comment: Entity framework contains default functionality for logging. Checkout the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception

Keep in mind this has massive performance impact, this is not suitable for production usage.